# Count unique rows

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Im having this problem where im trying to count the number of entries by a unique value.

```
SELECT table1.PID, table2.CID

FROM table1 

INNER JOIN table2 using (OID)

WHERE table1.PID IN (
    SELECT table1.PID
    FROM table1 
    JOIN table2 using (OID)
    WHERE table2.CID = 'A'
) AND table2.CID != 'A'
```

what I would like to do is to count the number of unique `table2.CID` entries.

**NOTE:** I need to do grouping cause of duplicate values.

Just to help, here is a picture of the table i'm getting as an output. What I would like to have is the count of each name on unique ID values. So ERNSH should return 7 and not 15.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to count unique rows or list unique rows?

Comment: MySQL or SQLite? Please remove the wrong tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want one record per CID, so group by CID. Then use COUNT. And as you want to count distinct values use COUNT(DISTINCT):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT table1.PID), table2.CID
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 using (OID)
WHERE table1.PID IN (
    SELECT table1.PID
    FROM table1 
    JOIN table2 using (OID)
    WHERE table2.CID = 'A'
) AND table2.CID != 'A'
GROUP BY table2.CID;
```

Comment: amazing.. I spent 1 hour trying to do exactly the same thing. Thanks alot!